# lsof showing unlinked file for more than one process

Tags: unix, inode, lsof

can anyone explain how unlinked file can be held by more than one process? currently I see four processes for the same inode 1543

```
# /usr/local/bin/lsof +aL1 /dev/vg00/lvol4

Xvnc      20622 p32adm    2u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
vncconfig 20649 p32adm    1u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
vncconfig 20649 p32adm    2u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
xterm     20650 p32adm    1u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
xterm     20650 p32adm    2u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
twm       20651 p32adm    1u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
twm       20651 p32adm    2u   REG 64,0x40004 4587683840     0 1543 /home (/dev/vg00/lvol4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no particular reason to expect different processes not to share an unlinked file as already answered by Marcus Müller, in your case these files are the processes `stdout` and `stderr`.

I guess these processes all inherited these file descriptors from an original command launched this way:

```
Xvnc ... > someLogFile 2>&1
```

and later, `someLogFile` was removed to (unsuccessfully) recover space.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain how unlinked file can be held by more than one process?

Yes, someone can.

First of all, the fact that it's unlinked now doesn't necessarily mean it was unlinked when the processes got their file handles.

But looking at your list, I'd presume these are things like shared memory segments, which don't need to have a filesystem node somewhere.

EDIT: OP asked for explanation of Shared Memory segments in comments, so here it is:

Modern CPUs and OSes isolate the address spaces of processes from each other, so process A can't access the memory of process B. If now A and B need to exchange information, one way of doing so is asking the operating system to map a few addresses into the respective memory spaces which are /the same/ memory for both processes. These segments need handles, and these handles are what I was referring to. For further information, `man shm_overview`.

Comment: thank you for explanation Marcus, seems even this is above my understanding. by shared memory segments you mean piece of information which is shared between processes like inode number in order to let other processes/threads to write to the same file? Regarding the first point it sounds logically that every file get it's file descriptor thus the only thing which comes to my mind is that the file was deleted.